# Life cycle transform in hooks for a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this componentWillReceiveProps life cycle in my code and I want to write it for a functional component. As I saw, this is possible only with React Hooks. The problem is I did not understood the very well and I need some help.

So, how would be this written in a functional component?

I saw some examples, but not exactly like this case.

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (newProps) => {
    const apiData = newProps.apiData;

    if (apiData.articles) {
        this.setState(() => ({
            pageLoading: false,
            articles: apiData.articles.articles,
        }), () => {
            //this.filterDisplayedArticles()
        })
    } else if (apiData.articleSearch && apiData.articleSearch.success) {
        let articles = apiData.articleSearch.articles;
        this.setState(() => ({
            pageLoading: false,
            articles: articles
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reading `useEffect()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `useEffect` hook here to apply a change based on the parameters needed 
And use the `useState` hook to track your state

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function DoSomething({ apiData }) {
  const { articles, articleSearch } = apiData;
  const { state, setState } = useState({ pageLoading: true, articles: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (articles) {
      setState({
        pageLoading: false,
        articles: apiData.articles.articles
      });
    } else if (articleSearch && articleSearch.success) {
      setState({
        pageLoading: false,
        articles: articleSearch.articles
      });
    }
  }, [articles, articleSearch]);

  return <div>I'm {state.pageLoading ? "loading" : "done loading"}</div>;
}
```

[**Play with it live :)**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-w866i)

Answer (score 0):

you can use useState hook for state management and componentwillrecieveprops,didmount,and willmount for useEffect hook lets see below code for functional component

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'

const App =() =>{
  const [pageLoading,setLoading] = useState(false)
const [articles,setarticles] = useState([])
useEffect((newProps) => {
  const apiData = newProps.apiData;

if (apiData.articles) {
  setLoading(false)
  setarticles(apiData.articles.articles)

} else if (apiData.articleSearch && apiData.articleSearch.success) {
 let articles = apiData.articleSearch.articles;
  setLoading(false)
 setarticles(articles)
}
 }, [pageLoading,articles])  
 return (
   ....child
 )
}
  export default App
```